# Applying 1 gram-force for 1000 seconds to 1kg mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, orbital-motion, propulsion

I am looking into ion thrusters and the small amount of propulsion they provide.
I am really new to this, so I want to understand. If we have mass of 1 kg in space and we are able to apply to it a 1 gram-force (which from my understanding would be quite good for some ion thrusters) what would be the effect on that 1kg mass?

When would it start moving? Would it start moving? When would it reach any significant speed (few meters per seconds?) and how could I calculate this in a simple way in the future? (Keep in mind that I don't have amaizng math skills above highschool)

Thank you so much!

(Note: as per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilogram-force), "a gram-force is 9.80665 mN")

Comment: The gram is not a unit of force, the Newton is.

Comment: Voting to reopen. The question is perfectly clear as long as you are not needlessly pedantic. Obviously "1 gram of force" is intended to mean $0.001g = 0.0098$ Newtons.

Comment: Thank you @gandalf61 for clarifying! I'll make sure to use better terms in the future and be more clear :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Newton’s laws F=ma. If a net force is applied to a body it *will* accelerate. With no net force the body remains in a state of constant motion, either at rest or with constant velocity in a straight line.

When a body is accelerated its velocity will be a*t plus any initial velocity v_0.
Inserting this in the initial equation for force we find v=Ft/m +v_0

If we let 1 gram force = .0098N then the velocity of a 1Kg object after 1000s starting from rest is easy to calculate.

This is true as long as the velocity of the body is small compared to c. For relativistic velocities you need a different equation. However, this won't happen after several minutes of acceleration with this force applied.

As InfiniteZero pointed out in his comment, for a more accurate answer you will have to take into account the decreasing mass of your rocket as fuel is expended. The simple equation becomes F=m(t)a , where mass is a function of time and you will have to use integration to get the final answer.

Comment: @infinitezero True, but this thrust for 1000s would consume less that 0.5g xenon, by which time the mass will have achieve a velocity of a few m/s, an error of a tiny fraction of 1%.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. It gives me some basis to explore on.
Assuming the mass is constant for simplification, how can I integrate the first equation of v=Ft/m+v_0?

I integrated v=Ft/m and the result after 1000s comes 0.98 m/s and for 100s 0.098 m/s which made me realise I was not taking into account that at every second there is a "previously achieved" velocity right?

Comment: No need for integration in that case. Simple multiplication, as you did, gives you the correct result. After 1000s you'll have a speed of 9.8m/s.